# How to create multiple different connections from a producer web part?

Tags: 2010, web-part, connected-web-parts

I have twwo webparts, one consumer and one producer. Consumer WebPart takes various ITransformableFilterValues connections. And Producer WebPart generates one ITransformableFilterValues connection.

Now, I need to send another filter field to the Consumer WebPart. I know consumer it is going to manage it well, but I don't know how to generate two different ITransformableFilterValues connections from the Producer WebPart. Could you help me?

The code I have to generate one connection is the next:

```
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> ParameterValues
    {
        get
        {

            string[] values = new string[] { fieldToSend };
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(values);
        }
    }

    [ConnectionProvider("People Picker Filter", "ITransformableFilterValues", AllowsMultipleConnections = true)]
    public ITransformableFilterValues SetConnectionInterface()
    {
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible to create more than one connection between two webparts...

Answer (score 1):

Create two parameters in the class and add another method, like such:

```
string test1;
string test2;

[ConnectionProvider("People Picker Filter1", "ITransformableFilterValues", AllowsMultipleConnections = true)]
public ITransformableFilterValues SetConnectionInterface()
{
    return test1;
}

[ConnectionProvider("People Picker Filter2", "ITransformableFilterValues", AllowsMultipleConnections = true)]
public ITransformableFilterValues SetConnectionInterface2()
{
    return test2;
}
```

Comment: Yes it works, but I think it is not possible to create more than one connection between two webparts